# There was an error when saving... Quickbooks error message: This transaction action is not allowed for this user

Tags: invoice, accounting

Tenant received this error when trying to export an invoice. In this case, it's for invoices, but there was also one for CreditMemo, so this can happen for other exports.

Comment: I don't see a programming question here

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the error was that the date range for the invoices they were exporting were closed off in Quickbooks. They changed the date to one outside of the closed dates, and were able to export without issue.